# cite tag does not make text italic in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I need to make some movie titles italic.  I think the cite tag is the correct way to do it, but it doesn't work - at least in Chrome.  Does anyone know why?

```html
<div>
  <p>New York City, 16 Nov-17 Dec 2017: <cite>wall cuts, train stations, New York City</cite> to be screened in “Open &#40;C&#41;all: Truth,” group show at BRIC, Brooklyn, NY;</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can make a safe reset if it has nothing to do with the font you are using.

`cite {
font-style:italic
}` My chrome does not need this. You piece of code works fine

Comment: it had not occurred to me, but I am using a font from Typekit.  So I guess I need to sync the italic version of the font.  But how do I wrap the movie title in the italic version and leave the rest regular?  Would that be best done using a span tag?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the `font-style` of `cite` to italic